# Reverse for 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' not found

Tags: python-3.x, django, summernote

I am having these type of error while clicking "add post" button  in django-admin section.
here's the error log info :

```
In template C:\Users\niraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19

Reverse for 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' not found. 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
9               {% for field in line %}
10                  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
11                      {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
12                      {% if field.is_checkbox %}
13                          {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
14                      {% else %}
15                          {{ field.label_tag }}
16                          {% if field.is_readonly %}
17                              <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
18                          {% else %}
19                              {{ field.field }}
20                          {% endif %}
21                      {% endif %}
22                      {% if field.field.help_text %}
23                          <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
24                      {% endif %}
25                  </div>
26              {% endfor %}
27          </div>
28      {% endfor %}
29  </fieldset>
```

here's the admin.py file given below:

```
from .models import Post
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

class PostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('content',)

admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```

here is the urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

i am not able to find out the error

Comment: Add `path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls'))` to your `urlpatterns`

Comment: thanks , problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

**Add this urls.py :**
`path('editor/', include('django_summernote.urls')),`